# How do I use variables inside lower level callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use WebSockets for the first time, and I'm making a todo list app. I'm using Express and Socket.io and Redis.

In the following code, socket.emit('items', {items: redisItems}) is failing, saying that emit can't be done on undefined. I know that client.hgetall is an asynchronous call and that I have to somehow get it to execute the after. How do I fix it? Do I use something like Futures or can this be done with a small fix on what I have right now?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('getItems', function (socket){
    var redisItems = new Array;
    callback = function(err,obj){
      for ( att in obj) {
        item = new Object();
        item.key = att;
        item.done = obj[att];
        redisItems.push(item);
        console.log(redisItems.length);
        console.log(item.key);
      }
      socket.emit('items', {items: redisItems})
    };
    client.hgetall("items", callback);
  });
});
```

Sidenote: What I currently have goes like this: 1) browser requests page 2) Once the browser has the page, it connects through WebSocket and asks for the todo items (so 2 requests).
In the future, I would prefer something like 1) browser makes request for page 2) server gives page and sends items once it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your socket object in the `getItems` callback.  While the initial `io.sockets` connection event returns the `socket`, subsequent `socket.on` events don't return another `socket` object, they return data for the event.  Try something like:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('getItems', function (data){
    var redisItems = new Array;
    callback = function(err,obj){
      for ( att in obj) {
        item = new Object();
        item.key = att;
        item.done = obj[att];
        redisItems.push(item);
        console.log(redisItems.length);
        console.log(item.key);
      }
      socket.emit('items', {items: redisItems})
    };
    client.hgetall("items", callback);
  });
});
```